# Javascript push Array items in Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following issue for creating a object in Javascript

When a user clicks a button I want to push the sn_slab to the array slabs. But each serial_number is grouped by the batch_number.

The object should look something like this

```
    var Object = {
    'COFBP21018': {
        slabs: {
            0: 18765,
            1: 38947,
            ...
        }
    },
    'DEPOUS394O': {
        slabs: {
            0: 11006276,
            1: 11020446,
                    ...

        }
    },
    ..
}
```

my html looks like this

```
<a href=".." class="add_slab_to_array" data-batch_nr="COFBP21018" data-sn_slab="18765" />
<a href=".." class="add_slab_to_array" data-batch_nr="COFBP21018" data-sn_slab="38947" />
<a href=".." class="add_slab_to_array" data-batch_nr="DEPOUS394O" data-sn_slab="11006276" />
<a href=".." class="add_slab_to_array" data-batch_nr="DEPOUS394O" data-sn_slab="11020446" />

var block = {};
$('.add_slab_to_array').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var batch_nr = $( this ).attr('data-batch_nr');
        var sn_slab = $( this ).attr('data-sn_slab');

        // Create new object if batch_nr does not exists
        // ADD sn_slab to Array inside the Object with related batch_nr

      block[batch_nr] = {
           slabs: [],
           add: function(sn_slab) {
               this.slabs.push(sn_slab)
           }
       }

       block[batch_nr].add(sn_slab);

 });
```

The code above works, but my array slabs is always overridden.

Comment: Anchors are not self closing elements ?

Comment: And you realize that you're using the same key for several of those, so they will be overwritten when you use COFBP21018 twice etc.

Comment: @martinezjc - right smack in the middle of the code

Comment: Sorry i was watching first at the json object

Comment: Other than the mentioned problems, it works fine -> **http://jsfiddle.net/8bvXz/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you're redefining the block object each time you click. You should instead check if it's set before proceeding.

```
block[batch_nr] = block[batch_nr] || {};

block[batch_nr].slabs = block[batch_nr].slabs || [];

block[batch_nr].add = block[batch_nr].add || function(sn_slab) {                         
            this.slabs.push(sn_slab);
           };
```

Comment: I don't think it needs to be this complicated... I think your diagnosis is correct, but I think the OP's code just needs the initial guard condition to prevent `block[batch_nr]` from being reinitialized

Answer (score 0):

Consider this

```
     block[batch_nr] = {
       slabs: [],
       add: function(sn_slab) {
           if (block[batch_nr]) {
               block[batch_nr].slabs.push(sn_slab)
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Very insightful answer!